# how can i resolve thi error in Navit

Tags: navigation

i working in navit...now i am met with this error...any body help me to solve this

```
 user@blrkrts0057pc:~$ cd /home/user/navit-0.2.0/navit
 user@blrkrts0057pc:~/navit-0.2.0/navit$ ./navit navit1.xml
  Running from source directory
 graphics_qt_qpainter:graphics_priv*  graphics_qt_qpainter_new(navit*,graphics_methods*,     attr**, callback_list*):enter
graphics_qt_qpainter:graphics_priv* graphics_qt_qpainter_new(navit*, graphics_methods*,   attr**, callback_list*):return
navit:plugin_load:can't load '/home/user/navit-0.2.0/navit/gui/qml/.libs/libgui_qml.so', Error '/home/user/navit-0.2.0/navit/gui/qml/.libs/libgui_qml.so: undefined symbol: _ZN8NGQProxy16staticMetaObjectE'
navit:main_real:Error parsing 'navit1.xml': Element 'gui' within unexpected context 'gui'. Expected 'navit' at line 46, char 164
```

Answer (score 0):

This error

```
/home/user/navit-0.2.0/navit/gui/qml/.libs/libgui_qml.so: 
undefined symbol: _ZN8NGQProxy16staticMetaObjectE
```

usually means that library versions somehow don't match. Try to compile and run Navit and all the plugins on the same system, and see if the problem persists.

```
navit:main_real:Error parsing 'navit1.xml':
Element 'gui' within unexpected context 'gui'. 
Expected 'navit' at line 46, char 164
```

This looks like an error in your navit1.xml (though it might be caused by the previous error). Have you tried correcting navit1.xml? Is there really an error in it?